# How to solve SQL unrequited pairs

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi My problem is that I have to list out all the unrequited relationships (A likes B but B didn't like A)

```
A B 
1 2 
2 1 
3 1
```

In this example my solution would be the pair of 3 1 (becoz 1 likes 2 and 2 also like 1 backs)
How should I express it in form of SQL?

Comment: Answer: use `NOT EXISTS (...)`

Answer (score 4):

You can formulate the query very similar to the way you have written the question. You are looking for rows of "A likes B" for which no "B likes A" rows exist.

Assuming the name of the table is `mytable`:

```
select *
from mytable t1
where not exists (
  select *
  from mytable t2
  where t1.A = t2.B and t1.B = t2.A
);
```

Answer (score 3):

With a self `LEFT` join that returns only the unmatched rows:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1 left join tablename t2
on t2.a = t1.b and t2.b = t1.a
where t2.a is null
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gULvm6uT2uAc9aJsoa5sK2/0).
Results:

```
| A   | B   |
| --- | --- |
| 3   | 1   |
```

Answer (score 3):

MySQL conveniently supports tuples with `in`.  So one method is:

```
select t.*
from t
where (b, a) not in (select a, b from t);
```

One caution is that this will not work if `a` or `b` are `NULL` (but I'm guessing that cannot be the case in this example).

As a general rule, I recommend `exists` for this purpose, as in C.C.'s answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use NOT IN wit SLEECT all id that have a match

> ```
> CREATE TABLE rel (
>   `A` INTEGER,
>   `B` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO rel
>   (`A`, `B`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '2'),
>   ('2', '1'),
>   ('3', '1');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT A,B FROM rel WHERE A NOT IN (SELECT r1.A FROM rel r1 INNER JOIN rel r2 ON r1.A = r2.B and r1.B = r2.A)
> ```
>
> ```
>  A |  B
> -: | -:
>  3 |  1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=daa757420df835ffdcc241789eac00f4)*